# Calculating with items enclosed in list positions (genetic algorithms fitness)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, probability, genetic-algorithm

```
population = [[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1], [0]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [1]],
 [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [4], [2]],
 [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3], [3]]]

def ProbabilityList2(population):
    fitness = [chromosome[1] for chromosome in population]
    total_weight=sum(fitness)
    relative_fitness= [(chromosome[1]+1)/total_weight for chromosome in population]
    return (relative_fitness)
```

I am trying to return a list based on proportional fitness values, in the following logic: `[[chromosome],[fitness],[counter]]`. All I want to do is to generate a list of probabilities based in this operation for all items (individuals) in the list, but I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

I solved that before using a dictionary, however during the loops of the program I get duplicated entries and the selection function crashes, since the number of individuals in the population and the probabilities (indexed by position) are uneven. Any thoughts on how I can calculate it in this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
def probabilityList2(population):    
    fitness = [chromosome[1][0] for chromosome in population]
    total_weight=sum(fitness)
    relative_fitness= [((chromosome[1][0])+1)/total_weight for chromosome in population]
    return relative_fitness


probabilityList2(population)
```

Answer (score 3):

`chromosome[1]` is a list. You can access it with `chromosome[1][0]`, or just store it outside of a list.
`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `fitness` list is the list of fitness from population. So, to get the sum of fitness, you've to get the sum of sub-lists in it by looping through the range.

```
def ProbabilityList2(population):
    fitness = [ chromosome[1] for chromosome in population ]
    total_weight=0
    for i in range(len(fitness)):
        total_weight+=sum(fitness[i])
```

This will give you the following fitness list and the sum

```
[[1], [3], [4], [3]] # fitness list
11                   # sum
```